# How to POST data from pure HTML website to Laravel API

Tags: jquery, laravel, api

I have a HTML website that post data to laravel API but the data is not saving in the database and it is not showing any error message.
This is the jquery im using inside the html page

```
  <script>
$("#submit").click(function(){
  var inputs = {};
  inputs.fullname = $("#Fullname").val();
  inputs.email = $("#Email").val();
  inputs.constituent = $("#Constituent").val();
  inputs.subject = $("#Subject").val();
  inputs.message = $("#Message").val();
  $.ajax({
      url : "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/complaints/",
      type: "POST",
      data: inputs,
      returnType: "JSON",
      success: function(response)
      {
        alert("Complaint sent!");
      },
      error: function(a, b, c)
      {
        alert("Error!");
      }
  });
})
```

this is the api.php

`Route::post("complaints", [ApiController::class, 'store']);`

And this is my controller

```
    {
        $v = new Feedback;
        $v->FullName = $request->FullName;
        $v->Constituent = $request->Constituent;
        $v->Email = $request->Email;
        $v->Subject = $request->Subject;
        $v->Message = $request->Message;
        $v->save();
    }
```

Comment: Can you dd first row in the store method inside your controller and see if it reaches there ?

Comment: It is working up to save(); function.  That's where the problem is

Comment: What happens when it gets to save() ?  Anything in the database?  Anything in the laravel log files?  It would be extremely unlikely to just fail silently

Comment: It's not showing anything

Comment: @IbnAhmad post here the .env file and your Feedback model as well as feedback table please. that would help us a lot

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your laravel model and database migration files are correct?
Make sure the db configs in the env file.

note: no migration table file is required. The parts I have given below are sufficient for the process.

.env db config

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=xxx.xxx.xxx
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=xxx
DB_USERNAME=xxx
DB_PASSWORD=xxxxx
```

Table Model

```
class XXModel extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, SoftDeletes;

    protected $table        = 'dbq_xx_table'; // db table name
    protected $primaryKey   = 'id';
    public $timestamps      = true;
    protected $fillable     = [ // db colums
        'xx_1',
        'xx_2'       
    ];
}
```

Table data create

```
return XXModel::create([
  'xx_1'           => $request->xx_1,
  'xx_2'           => $request->xx_2,
]);
```

Table data update

```
return XXModel::where('id',$request->id)->update([ 
 'xx_1'           => $request->xx_1,
]);
```

The object returned by created is the model register object